# Changing image while hovering over image

Tags: html, css

So basically, I want it so when you hover over the image it changes to another picture.

This is my code.

```
#arsenal{
background-image: url(bilder/ArsenalU.jpg);
width:210px;
height:210px;
} 
#arsenal:hover {
background-image: url(bilder/Arsenal.jpg);
}

<div id="arsenal"> </div>
```

Comment: The code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/621h07b3/). Something else that we can't guess is causing some problem.

Comment: Some ideas on what this problem can be?

Comment: Can't really know. You didn't even say what's not working, e.g. you don't see any image at all? You see the first, but it's not changing when hovering? etc. It's really hard (actually impossible) to help without any details.

Comment: The second image is not coming up like when I'm hovering it won't show up.

Comment: A) Make sure that image actually exists. B) Do you see the hover image in the fiddle posted in my first comment here? Maybe whatever browser/device you're using doesn't even support hover.

Answer (score 0):

Hover image may have different size so you have to set the image's height and width.

```
#arsenal{
  background-image: url(bilder/ArsenalU.jpg);
  width:210px;
  height:210px;
} 

#arsenal:hover {
  background-image: url(bilder/Arsenal.jpg);
  height:210px;
  width:210px;
}

<div id="arsenal"> </div>
```

Or you can use inline Javascript

```
<img src='ArsenalU.jpg' onmouseover="this.src='Arsenal.png';" 
onmouseout="this.src='ArsenalU.png';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. However, the file path of the picture extensions is incorrect. I recommend you to work in 2 separate files, css and html. The code you wrote is working.